# Django REST API one endpoint for CRUD

Tags: python, rest, http, django-rest-framework

I am trying to map `GET/PUT/DELETE` HTTP methods  to a single Django REST API endpoint. I can override the default `get_queryset` method to essentially do a `GET` request for a specific model field in the DB but am unsure which class methods to override for `PUT/DELETE`.  If I'm using `postman` to perform `PUT/DELETE` I get a `method not allowed` error.

**Models.py**

```
class Computer(models.Model):
    computer_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.computer_id)
```

**Urls.py**

```
router.register(r'computer/(?P<comp_id>[0-9]+)',  ComputerViewSet, base_name='computers')
```

**Views.py**

```
class ComputerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = ComputerSerializer

    def get_queryset (self, *args, **kwargs):
        comp_id = self.kwargs['comp_id']
        queryset = Computer.objects.filter(computer_id=comp_id)
        return queryset
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class ComputerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Computer
        fields = ('id', 'computer_id', 'city', 'description')
```

So I tried overriding other methods unsuccessfully in the class in `Views.py` :

```
def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    computer = self.get_object()
    self.perform_destroy(computer)
    computer.delete()

def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #...
```

My goal is to have one endpoint with `GET/PUT/DELETE` capabilities. How can I go about starting this?

Comment: I have never used ModelViewSet views myself but reading https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset seems to indicate you only need to specify `queryset` and `serializer_class`. Try not defining `get_queryset()`.

Comment: @e1v1s What you mean by ***single end-point***?

Comment: @JPG I mean I want to be able to send a GET/PUT/DELETE request to computers/<computer_id> and be able to get that computer ID, update that computer ID, or delete it, all from that endpoint

Comment: What would be the value of `computer_id` if you wanna create a new computer instance?

Comment: That’s why I mentioned GET/PUT/DELETE and not POST. If I wanted to POST a new computer_id then it’d have to be to a different endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the operations like this.

```
class Example(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
         your code
         return Response(....)

    def post(self, request):
         your code
         return Response(....)

    def put(self, request):
        your code
        return Response(.....)

    def delete(self, request):
        your code
        return Response(....)
```

Comment: or you can use generic APIView

Comment: Can I use `get_queryset` to filter based on `computer/<computer_id>` before passing to these methods? How will Django know when a user sends a `PUT` vs. a `DELETE`?

Comment: Django automatically call DELETE method if request.method is delete.

Comment: You can user get_queryset in genericAPIviews

Comment: In that case you class definition becomes class Example(generics.CreateAPIView, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):